# Tell dispatch_main_queue to work up all its blocks from main queue?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I am doing a test with AFHTTPClient to test the backend response.

> ```
> __block id testedResponseObject = nil;
> [client getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
>     testedResponseObject = responseObject;
> } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
>     testedResponseObject = nil;
> }];
> [client.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
>
> STAssertNotNil(testedResponseObject, @"");
> ```

The problem with this is that it waits for all operations to finish but it does not execute the success block because it gets scheduled to dispatch_get_main_queue(). Is there a way to tell dispatch_get_main_queue() to finish its blocks from the main queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on `completionBlock`, you can access the `responseData` (or whatever property) directly:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
[client enqueuHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
[client.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

STAssertNotNil(operation.responseData, @"");
```

Comment: Thanks that works. (I am using AFTHTTPClient so i get the operation from [client.operationQueue lastObject])